# unexpected token in json request with jquery / ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm using Jquery to fetch a json file, and I'm getting errors in the browser (Unexpected token : )

Here's my javascript:

```
fetchScenes: function() {
        $j.ajax({
            crossDomain:true,
            url: 'xml/scenes.json',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( sceneXML ) {

            }
        }); 
    },
```

Here's a partial structure from my json:

```
{ "scenes": {
    "scene": {
      "-id": "0",
      "-name": "Master",
      "scene": [
        {
          "-id": "1",
          "-name": "Weekday Vehicle",
          "-description": "Your home away from home.",
          "scene": [
            {
              "-id": "10",
              "-name": "For My Commute",
              "scene": [
                {
                  "-id": "13",
                  "-name": "Heading to School",
                  "scene": [
                    {
                      "-id": "20",
                      "-name": "Style Seeker",
                      "-vehicles": "1,3,6"
                    },
                    {
                      "-id": "21",
                      "-name": "Creative Thinker",
                      "-vehicles": "9,0,3"
                    }
                  ]
                },
```

I validated the JSON with JSONLint, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: When does the error occur? On request or on response? Need more debugging as from what you've described it *seems* correct.

Comment: It occurs with the JSON file itself (scenes.json, line 2)

Comment: If you tell jQuery to expect JSONP, you have to send JSONP, not JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP Otherwise, jQuery is evaluating the content as JavaScript, which generates an error... Or if it is actually not a cross-domain request, change `dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tell jQuery to expect JSONP, you have to send [JSONP *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), not JSON.

I.e. the response would be `someFunctionName({...json here...});` where `someFunctionName` is usually the value of the `callback` parameter sent with the URL (generated by jQuery automatically).

jQuery is evaluating the response as JavaScript, which generates an error in your case, since plain JSON is invalid JavaScript.

---

Or if it is actually not a cross-domain request (`xml/scenes.json` is a "local" URL), change `dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"` (and remove `crossDomain`).

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is invalid. I'm counting 7 opening curly braces and only three closing braces. Also, the number of brackets doesn't add up.

Comment: *"I validated the JSON with JSONLint, so I'm not sure what the problem is."* I assume he did not post everything. I think the problem is that he does not return JSONP.

Comment: Yes - the json is just a partial so you can see the structure. Felix - can you clarify what you mean in that it doesn't return JSONP?

Comment: @mheavers: JSON is what you have. JSONP is actually just JavaScript, and looks like `someFunctionName({...json here...});`.

Comment: Ah - okay - I thought I could force it (I feel like I've done that before, but it was on a server instead of the local file system) - I'm trying to get around a cross-domain issue, but I guess the only way to do that will be to put it in JSONP as you've listed. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, it didn't say partial JSON before. Personally, I would put a bit more effort in formulating my question. And besides, why not post the entire JSON when the error doesn't say where the parse error actually occurs? Also, I didn't notice the P in JSONP :)